# protractor downloaded filename

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to testing that if a certain file it's downloaded after click in a button. The process works, but the file downloaded in the test it's like this `.com.google.Chrome.uAjWNN`, but when i download the file from my app the file downloaded it's `05456342.txt`. My idea it's check the filename extension but because the file downloaded haven't, this is impossible.

**Why happen this?**

My protractor conf file

```
module.exports.config = {
  specs: [
    'test/e2e/features/*.feature'
  ],
  
  allScriptsTimeout: 60000,

  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: ['test/e2e/support/*.js', 'test/e2e/step_definitions/*_steps.js'],
    format: 'pretty',
    keepAlive: false
  },
  
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      'args': ['show-fps-counter=true'],
      'prefs': {
        'download': {
          'prompt_for_download': false,
          'default_directory': 'test/e2e/downloads/',
        }
      }
    }
  },

  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is before starting the execution delete all the files from the destination folder.After clicking on download button just validate if there is any new file is available in the destination folder. By doing this way you can verify whether the file is downloaded or not.

Comment: Oh, this is the way that i use to check if the file have been downloaded or not, but my idea is checking the extension of the file downloaded.